# Sort data in array with special key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How to sort data in array if key is not just string (at the first sight), but contains numbers separated by a character "_"

f.e.:

```
id_1_2_-1.25_0
id_1_2_-0.25_0
id_1_2_1.75_0
id_1_2_3_0
id_1_2_-4_0
id_1_2_0_0
```

`ksort()` can not be used, because "minus" symbol before value like `-1.25` is not recognized as negative number, but as special symbol

Important!! I can not separate just one number (-1.25, -0.25, 1.75, 3, -4, 0), other numbers could be also different like `id_9_4_-2.25_1` and array is sorted by all numbers between a character "_" f.e. first by `9`, then `4`, then `-2.25` and last one by `1`

I need result (sorted keys):

```
id_1_2_-4_0
id_1_2_-1.25_0
id_1_2_-0.25_0
id_1_2_0_0
id_1_2_1.75_0
id_1_2_3_0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spaceship operator has no trouble sorting arrays.  Just explode the keys each time.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Brt8E))

```
$indexes = [
    'id_1_2_3_0' => 1,
    'id_1_2_-0.25_0' => 2,
    'id_1_2_1.75_0' => 3,
    'id_1_2_-4_0' => 4,
    'id_1_2_0_0' => 5,
    'id_1_2_-1.25_0' => 6,
];

uksort($indexes, function($a, $b) {
    return explode('_', $a) <=> explode('_', $b);
});

var_export($indexes);
```

From PHP7.4 you can use the more concise arrow function syntax. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WGL15))

```
uksort($indexes, fn($a, $b) => explode('_', $a) <=> explode('_', $b));
```

---

p.s. if you really want to irritate future readers of your code,  you can explode each key, transpose (rotate it 90 degrees) the generated columnar data, then call `array_multisort()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WHqIZ))

```
[$c1, $c2, $c3, $c4, $c5] = array_map(null, ...array_map(fn($k) => explode('_', $k), array_keys($indexes)));
array_multisort($c1, $c2, $c3, $c4, $c5, $indexes);
```

Comment: easier than I expected - your is much more clean than has @Claudio, but both are working, so just thanks

Comment: @mickmackusa +1 for 7.4 syntax :)

Comment: @splash ...yeah, cheers, now that it's available, I'm trying to squeeze it into all my new answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can the array using the [ksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) function and specifying a callback function that compares each value individually using the [spaceship](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator like this:

```
$indexes = [
    'id_1_2_3_0' => 1,
    'id_1_2_-0.25_0' => 1,
    'id_1_2_1.75_0' => 1,
    'id_1_2_-4_0' => 1,
    'id_1_2_0_0' => 1,
    'id_1_2_-1.25_0' => 1,
];

uksort($indexes, function($current, $next) {
    // break the strings to compare the values individually (str_replace is used to remove the 'id_' from the key)
    $currentParts = explode('_', str_replace('id_', '', $current));
    $nextParts = explode('_', str_replace('id_', '', $next));

    foreach ($currentParts as $i => $part) {
        // edge case when the indexes have different lengths (can be removed if the keys always have the same length)
        if (!isset($nextParts[$i])) {
            return 0; // the strings don't have the same length
        }

        $comparisonResult = $part <=> $nextParts[$i];

        // if the values are different, the comparison result is returned
        if ($comparisonResult !== 0) {
            return $comparisonResult;
        }
    }

    // reaching this return means the keys being compared are equal
    return 0;
});
```

The result is ([PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7a0284d6d1e48fdb82c88b0ff00fda00b6df59e)) :

```
Array
(
    [id_1_2_-4_0] => 1
    [id_1_2_-1.25_0] => 1
    [id_1_2_-0.25_0] => 1
    [id_1_2_0_0] => 1
    [id_1_2_1.75_0] => 1
    [id_1_2_3_0] => 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it could be like

```
function getValue($raw) {
    $value = explode('_', $raw);

    return $value[count($value) - 2];
}

uksort($a, function ($a, $b) {
    $aKey = (float) getValue($a);
    $bKey = (float) getValue($b);

    return $aKey <=> $bKey;
});
```

Comment: this sorting array by numbers [-1.25, -0.25, 1.75, 3, -4, 0], I edited while you wrote this maybe, I wrote that array must be sorted by all numbers between a character "_", nevermind :) .. meanwhile someone wrote function what I need. But thanks for your time.